# C++ Templates - Add function only if certain value in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is what I'm trying here possible somehow?

I know that #if doesn't work with template parameters.

Please don't teach me how properties are against the idea of C++, that's not the question here.

```
typedef enum {
kPropertyReadWrite,
kPropertyReadOnly
} PropertyType;


template <typename T, PropertyType P = kPropertyReadWrite>
class property {
  T value;
public:
  property() {}
  property(T initValue) : value(initValue){}


#if P == kPropertyReadOnly
  T & operator = (const T &i) {
    //::std::cout << i << ::std::endl;

    return value = i;
  }
#endif

  operator T const & () const {
    return value;
  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question, but it is possible to add a function to a class only if a certain condition on the template parameter holds. Read about SFINAE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

Comment: Sure, by SFINAE, or by partial specialization. (Also, your condition seems backwards.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a template specialization:

```
typedef enum {
kPropertyReadWrite,
kPropertyReadOnly
} PropertyType;

template <typename T, PropertyType = kPropertyReadWrite>
class property {
  T value;
public:
  property() {}
  property(T initValue) : value(initValue){}

  operator T const & () const {
    return value;
  }
};

template <typename T>
class property<T, kPropertyReadOnly> {
  T value;
public:
  property() {}
  property(T initValue) : value(initValue){}

  T & operator = (const T &i) {
    std::cout << i << ::std::endl;
    return value = i;
  }

  operator T const & () const {
    return value;
  }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c24a91ced3b91a2)

Comment: Note: `PropertyType` is a type in the original code.

Comment: That sounds like the best solution so far, thank you. I wasn't aware I could "specify" a template like this.
'

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `PropertyType` is a non-type argument, notice there's no `typename`, my guess's probably a `typedef` of an integral type that's why the int in my code.

Comment: Actually, I tried it and it doesn't compile. It gives me "unknown type kPropertyReadOnly" for the second one. Apparently this is not allowed.

Comment: @keyboard Take a look at the demo provided. You must define `kPropertyReadOnly` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @101010: Yeah I know.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This works. Though you should add either an explicit constructor or delete the copy constructor and = operator for it to be the 100% answer, as others here suggested.

Comment: @keyboard why would you want to do that?

Comment: To cause a compiler error if you do readOnlyProperty = 2 or something similar. Otherwise I can still use the = operator, even if I shouldn't be able to.

Comment: @keyboard the `T & operator = (const T &i)` that you specified has nothing to do with the default assignment operator. This operator is only defined in the specialization.

Comment: The difference is that default assignment operator has a signature of `property& operator=(property const &other)` (i.e., you assign between objects of the class `property`).

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that so many people can't get the SFINAE right. The SFINAE condition needs to depend on a template parameter of `operator=`, and not the class template. Otherwise, instantiating the class template may cause a hard error.

```
template<PropertyType P1 = P, typename std::enable_if<P1 != kPropertyReadOnly, int>::type = 0>
T & operator = (const T &i) {
  //::std::cout << i << ::std::endl;

  return value = i;
}
```

Note that this is actually not sufficient to prevent `property<int, kPropertyReadOnly> p2; p2 = 10;` from compiling, because your code defines an implicit conversion from `T` to `property<T, ...>`, so the compiler will implicitly convert the `10` to a `property` and then call the copy assignment operator.

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't know "enable_if_t", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @keyboard `-std=c++14`, or write `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`.

Comment: What should I replace exactly? And what can I do to prevent p2 = 10 from compiling?

Comment: You must delete copy assignment operator or mark the constructor as explicit to prevent implicit conversion. Eg: `operator=(const property&) = delete`, `explicit property(T initValue)`

Answer (score 2):

This is easily achieved through `std::enable_if`:

```
template<PropertyType U = P, typename std::enable_if<P == kPropertyReadWrite, int>::type = 0> T& operator=(const T &i)
{ 
  return value = i;
}
```

[This](http://ideone.com/kGP95N) works by disabling the method if the condition is not met during compilation, raising a compilation error in this situation (or choosing another enabled implementation in a different scenario)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't compile. "No type named type".

Comment: Read the source, it is meant to not compile. Just remove the `property<int, kPropertyReadOnly> p2;
 p2 = 10; //compilation error`and it will. It is to show you how it works.

Comment: Except that just writing `property<int, kPropertyReadOnly> p2; ` is enough to cause it not to compile, without the assignment.

Comment: Yes, that's because I'm so used to use `T` as the type that I mismatched it with `typename U = P`.